# How can I link to different page and scroll to a specific section?

Tags: hyperlink, asciidoc

I want a link on page1.adoc to page2.adoc and then directly scroll/go to section 2 on this page. How can I do it? I can´t find a solution for my problem.

Comment: http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/linking.php. Look at link to fragment section

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are [Document to Document Cross References](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/inter-document-xref/). A simple example of 2 files referencing each other is:

**filea.adoc**

```
= doc A

[#linkdoca]
this is a text with the linkdoca id/reference

xref:fileb.adoc#linkdocb[go to linkdocb in fileb.adoc]
```

**fileb.adoc**

```
= doc B

[#linkdocb]
this is a text with the linkdocb id/reference

xref:filea.adoc#linkdoca[go to linkdoca in filea.adoc]
```

Both files are in the same folder, after converting them with asciidoctor the HTML files link to each other.

Comment: good answer which would deserved to be accepted.